# Widgets on BADA 2.0. How to start?

Tags: widget, bada

I want to make widget for BADA 2.0 which should be constantly shown on home screen. Samsung widgets developer forum are about to close(http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=12). So I ask here.
Please give me few advices:

- Which framework can I use WAC or Riff?
- Which IDE to use?
- How to pack widget and how to test?
- How to submit widget to App store?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Though there would be no forum solely for widget dev, 
you can submit your inquiry on bada development to bada Developers website.

It has forums also, supporting English, Chinese, Korean and Russian. 
http://developer.bada.com/badaforum/category/list.do?categoryId=21&menu=MC01050900